# change input value of hidden input in current document webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

here is the html

```
<input type="hidden" name="visited" value="aW5kZXgucGhwPw==" />
```

vb.net

```
dim PageElements As HtmlElementCollection WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

     For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElements
        If CurElement.GetAttribute("name") = "visited" Then
            CurElement.SetAttribute("value", "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
        End If
```

i want to change the value of this input on the current document webbrowser to be user in the next action with the new value

Answer (score 0):

you can change input value by JavaScript.

var input  = document.getElementById('visited'); 
input.value ="your new value";

You need to set id of your hidden field

Comment: the input has not id just name and how to integrate javascript in webbrowser control?